# How can I limit the number of iteration of a loop in a nesting loop function in Python?

Tags: python, function, loops, nested, iteration

How can I limit the number of iteration of a loop in a nesting loop function in Python?

**Code:**

```
friends= ['Ali', 'Asma','Amna', 'Izma', 'Omer','Zahid','Bilal','Sarah']
for vowelnames in friends:
    if vowelnames in ('Ali','Asma','Izma','Omer'):
        print('Oh my lovely friend ' + vowelnames + '! ,I would like you to come on my graduation ceremony')
    else:
        for cons in friends[:8]:
            if cons in ('Bilal','Sarah','Zahid'):
                print( cons + " I would like you to come on my graduation ceremony")
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Break out of the loop when you know that your condition is met or use while loop. Btw what are expecting? Please be specific.

Comment: I have no idea what you are even asking, but judging from the Question name, I think you might want to look into While loops?!

Comment: The second loop is completely useless. Just delete it and write `elif vowelnames in ('Bilal'...`

Comment: The output that I want is : ~~~Oh my lovely friend Ali! ,I would like you to come on my graduation ceremony
Oh my lovely friend Asma! ,I would like you to come on my graduation ceremony ~~~
 I would like you to come on my graduation ceremony
Oh my lovely friend Amna! ,I would like you to come on my graduation ceremony
Oh my lovely friend Omer! ,I would like you to come on my graduation ceremony
 I would like you to come on my graduation ceremony

Answer (score -1):

> You have to use "range"

```
friends= ['Ali', 'Asma','Amna', 'Izma', 'Omer','Zahid','Bilal','Sarah']
for i in range(x): #Here instead of x you can give a number so that the loop will run 
                   #till that number
    for vowelnames in friends:
        if vowelnames in ('Ali','Asma','Izma','Omer'):
            print('Oh my lovely friend ' + vowelnames + '! ,I would like you to come 
                  on my graduation ceremony')
else:
    for cons in friends[:8]:
        if cons in ('Bilal','Sarah','Zahid'):
            print( cons + " I would like you to come on my graduation ceremony")
```

Comment: You are running the complete code in another external loop, which is not what the OP wants (even though it is not clear what he *does* want)

Comment: Ok but still instead of that 'x' if he gives a lower value the loop will run a fewer times ! just as you said. @Aryerez

Comment: Without your addition, his code would run exactlly once. Now it will run "X" times (and do exactlly the same thing every time, since nothing changes inside his code in relation to "X"). I don't know of a way to make a loop run fewer times than 1.